# Handling huge amount of local database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a challenge in dealing with local database in android.
  I have nearly 6 GB of data and need to store in local db. Can SQLite handle this much of huge data. And I have to update db daily but its a little amount of data. Is it possible to handle 6 GB of data in local db. Or any other light weight databases to handle this.

Can anybody have any idea please suggest me.

Comment: yup u can handle but once issue will be apk size will be huge

Comment: Why apk size will be huge? For the first time I am downloading the data from the online and store it in local db. Can you please give me clear information on this?

Comment: so how many records do you expect to be in the sqlite db?

Comment: 100 million records and each record may have 11 columns.

Comment: since sqlite db is reside in apk.. if i m wrong plz correct me

Comment: sqlite can be saved in either device's local memory or in sd card. It own't occupies that much size in apk.

Comment: 100M records??? sqlite db can handle this but the performance can be poor, very poor

Comment: How much time it take to search a record from the whole db?

Comment: no idea, you have to try it...

Comment: I had read that the sqlite database file have a maximum size of 140 TB. So on the phone it usually is limited by your mass memory size(2 gb and so on). the memory size will limit how much data you can retrieve from a query. Android Cursors have a limit of 1 MB for the results.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html